# How do I post a lot of data to Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django, web

I am trying to send of list of files to my Django Website. Each set is transmitted with the following info:

- File name,
- File size,
- File location,
- File type

**Now, suppose I have 100 such sets of data, and I want to send it to my Django Website, what is the best method I Should use?**

PS: I was thinking of using JSON, and then POST that JSON data to my Django URL. The data might then look like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    { "filename":"Movie1" , "filesize":"702", "filelocation":"C:/", "filetype":"avi" }, 
    { "filename":"Movie2" , "filesize":"800", "filelocation":"C:/", "filetype":"avi" }, 
    { "filename":"Movie3" , "filesize":"900", "filelocation":"C:/", "filetype":"avi" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: POSTing a huge JSON object is a perfectly sensible approach, as far as I can see. Is there some reason that you don't want to use the solution you've outlined in your post?

Comment: `send of list of files to my Django Website` ... from server side to client side or client side to server side?

Comment: @MarkAmery yup, honestly, i am just unable to understand python's "json" library. And i don't have much experience with JSON on the web. I mean i know what JSON is, kinda know how it works, but never actually used it.

Comment: @AamirAdnan It's actually a native windows app written python (pyQt) sending a list to files to my Django Website.

Comment: Do you want to post the files too, or just the metadata?

Comment: @SkylarSaveland Nope, not the actual files, just the metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think sending json data to your server makes sense. Now to actually implement it, you would need your server to accept the http `POST` request that you will use to send the data about the files.

So, the server code may look like this:

## urls.py:

```
import myapp
#  ...
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^json/$',myapp.serve_json), #http://<site_url>/json/ will accept your post requests, myapp is the app containing view functions
                         #add other urls
                      )
#other code
```

## views.py

```
import json
def serve_json(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'files' in request.POST:
            file_list = json.loads(request.POST['files'])

            for file in file_list:
                #do something with each file dictionary in file_list
                #...
            return HttpResponse("Sample message") #You may return a message 
    raise Http404
```

Now in your Desktop application, once you have the list of the dictionaries of files, you may do this:

```
import urllib,json
data = urllib.urlencode({'files':json.dumps(file_dict)}) #file_dict has the list of stats about the files
response = urllib.urlopen('http://example.com/json/', data)
print response.read()
```

You may also look into `urllib2` and `httplib` and use them in place of `urllib`.

Comment: when I see no space after a comma, it makes me want to scratch my eyes out. Teach beginners to user pep8, please.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland Thanks for the suggestion. I am not so experienced either. Looked up pep8. Will try to follow it from now on.